# Prerequisite for Milnor Topology from a Differential Viewpoint

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

I finished Introduction to Manifold by Loring Tu and I am interested to study this book by Milnor. But I didn't take a course in topology (other than the one I learnt from the appendix of Tu's book). Is this sufficient for me to read the book by Milnor?

Comment: I'm not even sure that you will learn many new things from Milnor's book (which is great) if you already finished Tu's book.

Comment: @Zircht Intersection theory is not covered in Tu's.

Comment: Read Guillemin and Pollack which is somewhat an expanded version of Milnor's.